# best way to implement movement after A* pathfinding? tile-based movement vs pixel-based?

Tags: xna, algorithm, path-finding

I was able to implement the A* pathfinding algorithm to calculate a path from the enemy to player. [image]

After trying to do movement well, I realized I ran into all sorts of problems. I was able to add clearance to the pathfinding, so I'm now going to have sprites of variable size, which leads to even more issues.

I am currently doing movement like - 
path[0] is first Tile in path and it is removed when you get to it:

```
            if (path.Count > 0) {
                if (path[0].isTouching(this))
                    path.RemoveAt(0);                           
                }
            }

                            if (path [0].getCenterX() > this.getCenterX()) {
                                speedX = speed; 
                                speedY = 0;
                                System.Console.WriteLine("moving right");
                            }
                            else if (path [0].getCenterX() < this.getCenterX()) {   
                                speedX = -speed; 
                                speedY = 0; 
                                System.Console.WriteLine("moving left");
                            }

                            if (path [0].getCenterY() > this.getCenterY()) { 
                                speedX = 0; 
                                speedY = speed;
                                System.Console.WriteLine("moving down");

                            }
                            else if (path [0].getCenterY() < this.getCenterY()) {       
                                speedX = 0; 
                                speedY = -speed; 
                                System.Console.WriteLine("moving up");
                            }

                            this.move(speedX, speedY);
```

This doesn't work very well for a variety of reasons.

I am certain the pathfinding I implemented calculates the proper path of Tiles. Now I think I have to move from a pixel to pixel movement -> tile to tile in order to have this working better. This would probably help, right? How is movement usually done to work with A*? If the tile-based movement would aid, any tips on implementing this?

Comment: What about moving to the center of the tile (or the bottom) instead of the top-left corner?

Comment: the .getCenter() gets the center of the tile :P

Comment: I didn't read that part. Okay, nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about move horizontally and vertically at a same time, the problem is not here. You are doing fine. Maybe problem belong to input module.

About A*, it's a path finding algorithm, it return series of point present the path you ask for. Movement is another problem, don't stick it with A*. The easiest way to implement moving system are storing local goal, and once you reach local goal, go to next goal in path.

```
int position_x, position_y;
float speed_x, speed_y;
int local_goal_x, local_goal_y;
bool stop;
void next_goal(){
    path.removeAt(0);
    if(path.empty()){ stop = true; return;}
    local_goal_x = path[0].x;
    local_goal_y = path[0].y;
    speed_x = (local_goal_x - position_x)/10.0;
    speed_y = (local_goal_y - position_y)/10.0;
}
void update_moving()
{
    if(stop) return;
    position_x += speed_x;
    position_y += speed_y;
    if(position_x == local_goal_x && position_y == local_goal_y) next_goal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
int pixelPerFPS; // pixel per FPS
void move(int x, int y);
void update(int time)
{
    character.currentX += (character.goalX - character.currentX) / abs(character.goalX - character.currentX) * pixelPerFPS;
    character.currentY += (character.goalY - character.currentY) / abs(character.goalY - character.currentY) * pixelPerFPS;
    // do something
}
int gameStart()
{
    time2 = currentTime();
    while(running)
    {
        deltaTime = currentTime() - time2;
        time2 = currentTime();
        update(deltaTime);
        // do something
        // do other thing
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is very simple function like an example

If you want to make it more complex and flexible, you have to take care about frame per seconds (FPS)